# d3 real time graph ploting using mysql and streaming sensor data

Tags: javascript, mysql, d3.js

hey guys currently i am trying to plot a real time graph using d3js.I am sending temperature  values to a mysql database using esp8266 and a dht11 sensor.I have able to grab the  data from mysql and plot it using d3js.But i have to refresh the page continuously to update the graph.How can i update the graph continuously without refreshing the page ? or make it real time .....I am new to  d3js .....can anyone give me a example of such functionality use in d3js?...............(i dont want to use pubnub or other libraries....I want to learn to do it purely in d3js)

these are the code i am using

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Temperature</title>

<style>

  .axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke:blue;
  }

  .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    
  }
 

  .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

</style>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script>
//setting marging,height and width for the graph drawing area
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 200, left: 50},
    width = 1280 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 720 - margin.top - margin.bottom;




 //getting data from sensors using data.php which encoded the data to jason format...so we calling the json data here
 d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
     var k = [];  
   data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.event = d.event;
        d.sensor2 = +d.sensor2; 
        k.push(d.event)
      
    });


//defining x
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width])
    .domain(k);

//defining y 
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, null])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sensor2; })])



//defining the x Axes   
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(5);


//defining the y Axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(5);

// defining the line and drawing the line by  returning the x and y values 
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.event); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.sensor2); })
    

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    

//making the xAxes
  svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.70em")
            .attr("dy", ".70em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                });
//making the yAxes
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php files -----data.php

```html
<?php
header('Content_Type:application/json');
define('localhost','127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','skyline');
define('DB_NAME','arduino');
$mysqli=new mysqli(localhost,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed:".$mysqli->error);
}
$query =sprintf("SELECT id,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,event FROM tbard ORDER BY id");
$result =$mysqli->query($query);

$data =array();
foreach($result as $row){
 $data[]=$row;
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

sensors.php---

```html
<?php
   include("conn.php");
   
   $sensor1 =$_GET['sensor1'];
   $sensor2 =$_GET['sensor2'];
   $sensor3 =$_GET['sensor3'];
   
   $sql_insert="insert into tbard (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3)values('$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3')";
   
   mysql_query($sql_insert);
   
   if($sql_insert){
    echo"insert success";
   }else{
    echo "insert not success";
   }
   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using websockets. Since you are using php I would suggest looking into [Ratchet](http://socketo.me). You can't do it purely in d3 because it doesn't have a web sockets module.

Comment: no . I am not using nodejs ......I just need a  little help with my javascript code i want to get the sensor data  continuously from mysql database while updating the graph without refreshing the page.

Comment: sorry i didnt mention about the php backend i have created. i have edited the question.............

Comment: thnks for your help

Comment: @LuisVillavicencio *"You can't use d3 to get data"*... where did you get that information? https://github.com/d3/d3-request

Comment: Can you explain *why* is it different?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that library is a wrapper that has ajax and file I/O embedded in d3. You can get the same functionality from simple Ajax or xmlhttprequest without downloading a wrapper library.

Comment: That library *is* D3. besides that, you wrote "you can't use d3 to get data... you either need to use ajax" and then, when I showed you that D3 does get data, you replied "that's different, it is pretty much ajax calls". Isn't it contradictory?

Comment: I didn't know that there was a wrapper library for http requests for d3. It is not d3 (by reading the docs for that library) since you need to install it separate from the ACTUAL d3.js visualization library. You are just playing with my words. You don't even need that library when you can do ajax or xmlhttprequests. The question was realtime so I suggested websockets which is a better approach then http requests. Jeez.

Comment: I'm not playing with your words. That **is** D3, and that module is in the default (which you call "actual") D3 installation. As in D3 v4.x the modules can be installed separately, their API is separated, only that. You should not write about what you don't know.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i know about websockets and it is the approach i told him that it would be better to use. Even if that module was to be part of D3.js it would still not be a better approach than websockets for realtime. I still stand with my main answer. (:

Comment: @GerardoFurtado but I do agree I don't know much about D3.js since I barely use it! Nothing hard to learn about that tho. I will delete my comments about D3

Comment: Edited my main answer! Cheers.

Comment: thnks everyone for your help.I solved my problem using ajax

Comment: I hv dne the same thing using different protocols. First I have used mqtt protocol to send data .In that case i used eclipse paho javascript library to  write a programme to grab the data and plot it using d3.Here i configure linux ubuntu server as my broker in the  network and install ,configure websockets to used mqtt protocol to send data.But when i try to used http  protocol with ajax  it wasnt that much accurate or reliable  than the first method.May be it cause  http which has a heavy structure than  mqtt or  may be it cause   i used ajax rather than using websockets in the second method